# Prove that $\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}}\sin{\frac{x}{2}} \cdot [\sin{x}] = 0$

Tags: limits

How can I prove:

$$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}}\sin{\frac{x}{2}} \cdot [\sin{x}] = 0$$

I know that for every $0<x<\pi$, where $x\neq \pi/2$,  $[\sin{x}]=0$

How can I go from here?

Comment: Do you mean by [...] "integer part" ?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean

Comment: This might be helpful $x=[x]+\{x\}$ or $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \sin{\frac{x}{2}} \cdot \left( \sin{x} - \{\sin{x}\} \right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said yourself that $[\sin(x)] = 0$ for all $x \in (0, \pi)$ except at $x= \pi/2$.

Then $\sin(x/2)[\sin(x)] = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in (0, \pi) \text{ and } x \neq \pi/2 \\ 1 & x = \pi/2 \end{cases}$.  It follows from the definition of $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) = y$ that the limit as $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$ of this expression is $0$.  Recall the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition:

> $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) = y$ means for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ so that $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - y| < \epsilon$.  **Note the $0 < |x -a|$ part, which means we are only considering points near $a$, but not the value $a$ itself, since if $x = a$, then $|x - a| = 0$.**

It's your job to now fill in the details/apply this definition based on the hint I gave above.

Comment: The definition of limit implies $0 < | x − a | < \delta $! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Functions_of_a_single_variable

Comment: @EugenCovaci I didn't write it, but I think you can exclude the point $a$ from the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition for $x \to a$.  We care about the behavior of the function *near* $a$, but not necessarily *at* $a$.

Comment: @rtybase I don't understand the significance of your comment.

Comment: @user46944 it's the $| x − a | < \delta $ vs $0 < | x − a | < \delta $ In this case you are right and EugenCovaci is wrong (including his -1 downvote).

Comment: @rtybase Good point! :) Thank you!!! I was questioning what's wrong with the definition I wrote and how we can exclude $\pi/2$.  It's because $x = \pi/2$ makes $|x - \pi/2| = 0$.  Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

You almost answered the question yourself. The limitand is zero in a neighborhood of the point. Sine is continuous on a neighborhood of the point. What happens at $x=\pi/2$ is irrelevant; it's zero from the right and the left.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, defining the domain would be helpful for those of use trying to help you. Are these defined over $\Bbb R$?  Try using the properties of limits: $Lim$(fg)=lim(f)lim(g). Then, we can focus on each limit individually.  Also, as stated by @GFauxPas, analyze the left and right sided limits. Good luck